# siunitx alsoload option high energy physics

Tags: siunitx

Until now (before release 2013/07/31) it was possible to use the option `alsoload=hep`.

```
\usepackage[alsoload=hep]{siunitx}
```

Actually I do not see how it should be possible to load the `\gauss` unit (from high energy physics) in the new release.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(If you need a quick solution, load the option `version-1-compatibility`;

```
\usepackage[version-1-compatibility]{siunitx}
```

However, since the new version of `siunitx`, the following is more appropriate:)

Just declare the unit by yourself as described on page 39 in the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\gauss{G}

\begin{document}
$\SI{3}{\gauss}$
\end{document}
```

The loadable special units are not longer available: see the manual for an explanation of why.

**Edit**

To provide all the `hep` functionality you may type:

```
% High energy physics
\DeclareSIUnit\micron{\micro\metre}
\DeclareSIUnit\mrad{\milli\rad}
\DeclareSIUnit\gauss{G}
\DeclareSIUnit\eVperc{\eV\per\clight}
\DeclareSIUnit\nanobarn{\nano\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\picobarn{\pico\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\femtobarn{\femto\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\attobarn{\atto\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\zeptobarn{\zepto\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\yoctobarn{\yocto\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\nb{\nano\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\pb{\pico\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\fb{\femto\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\ab{\atto\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\zb{\zepto\barn}
\DeclareSIUnit\yb{\yocto\barn}
```

Comment: You may also declare those in a file `siunitx.cfg` and load it before `\sisetup`. With `\ProvidesFile{siunitx.cfg}` you'll have your own settings always available.